# okhttp response body 'not available' despite other clients being able to do so

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I created a simple web server to test GET and POST requests on Android Studio using the OKHTTP library. The initial server I was pinging data from ran on Node/Express and communicated well with Android Studio, but when I moved the server to an ESP8266, which sends the same data in the response, the app I'm building would suddenly crash. Find the entire source code for the GET request pasted below:

```
public void getStatus () {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(BASE_URL).build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            assert response.body() != null;
                            String rawData = response.body().string();
                            JSONObject rsp = new JSONObject(rawData);
                            lightState = rsp.getJSONObject("data").getString("status");
                            textView.setText(lightState);
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Upon closer inspection with the Android Studio debug tools, I realized it was the `String rawData = response.body().string();` line that would cause a fatal exception. This led me to the network tools, which revealed that the response body was showing up as "Not Available":
[Android Studio Network Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kVjh.png)

This is peculiar to me because every other client I've used to send the request (Chrome, Thunder Client, cURL) has produced the expected response:
[Thunder Client Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfuF0.png)

[Chrome Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLlG3.png)
[Chrome Response 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/464eA.png)

[cURL Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K9a8.png)

It makes no sense to me, and leads me to believe that something must be wrong with my code in Android Studio.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I don't know where to go from here. Cheers!

Edit: I implemented the HttpLoggingInterceptor and I am confused because the Logcat entries do show the data I am expecting.

```
2023-04-26 21:11:49.786 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  --> GET http://BASE_URL
2023-04-26 21:11:49.787 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  --> END GET
2023-04-26 21:11:50.023 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  <-- 200 OK http://BASE_URL (235ms)
2023-04-26 21:11:50.024 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
2023-04-26 21:11:50.024 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  Content-Length: 73
2023-04-26 21:11:50.025 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
2023-04-26 21:11:50.025 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  Connection: keep-alive
2023-04-26 21:11:50.026 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  Keep-Alive: timeout=2000
2023-04-26 21:11:50.037 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  {"success":false,"error":"method not allowed","data":{"status":"denied"}}
2023-04-26 21:11:50.037 28252-30711 okhttp.OkHttpClient     com.example.myapplication            I  <-- END HTTP (73-byte body)
```

Edit 2: I noticed that while I have the interceptor attached, the request is successful. Removing it and using the builder still causes the app to crash.

Edit 3: I noticed that every other client receives the `connection: close` header except the one in Android Studio, that one receives 'keep-alive' as the value.

Comment: You should add http-logging-interceptor to get a more detailed log in your logcat. That would help others to debug your code.

Comment: @fshdn19 Thank you for your feedback, I have implemented the interceptor and updated my post. I thought it would clear things up but I am more confused now as the Logcat entries to reflect the data I am expecting.